# LocalBroadcast not working inside worker thread despite using Looper.getMainLooper()

Tags: android, handler, android-broadcast, android-handler, localbroadcastmanager

I am trying to work on a screen(say Activity A) where there is a progress bar displayed on the screen and I need to send a broadcast to a different activity(Activity B) broadcastReceiver while the progressbar is running. And if the function in the activity B is completed it will display that back to this activity A.

Now I am running progress bar in a worker thread like this and sending localbroadcast using handler(Looper.getMainLooper()):

```
final Context context = Activity.this.getApplicationContext();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     while (progressBar.getProgress() != 100) {
        try {
            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(2);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Interrupted exception in progress bar: " + ie);
        }
        if (progressBar.getProgress() == 10) {
           Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // model is a parameter which I want to send using intents
                   Intent intent = new Intent("new_device");
                   intent.putExtra("device", model);
                           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
               }
           });
        }
     }
  }
}).start();
```

But it's not working. Broadcast is not received by the other activity.
I know that Broadcast should be done on UI thread and it works fine if I do it in onResume() or onCreate() method. But when I'm using it in a handler inside a thread (inside onCreate()) it is not working.

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way of doing it?

#### EDIT

I am receiving my intent in Activity B as follows:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Model model = (Model) intent.getSerializableExtra("device");
            onConnectDevice(model.getDevice());
        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you registering your receiver? How?

Comment: Yes I am registering my receiver in Activity B's onCreate() method:
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("new_device"));

Comment: You could start by adding a debug flag to your intent so that you can check whats crops up in the logs.

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using runonuithread method of the activity inside your thread

Comment: you mean the activity which contains the thread? Like this :
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // model is a parameter which I want to send using intents
                   Intent intent = new Intent("device");
                   intent.putExtra("device", model);
                           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
               }
           });

Comment: You can juse use Activity.this.runOnUiThread. also register your reciever in the oncreate by passing broadcast receiver and intent filter to the registerreceiver method

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. runOnUiThread also doesn't work and I have no idea why!

Comment: Yes I have registered my receiver in Activity B's onCreate() method. See my above comment.
But still it doesn't work with runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in `progressBar.incrementProgress()`, because you are trying to alter a UI element from outside the UI thread. Keeping your structure, you can try something like:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     while (progressBar.getProgress() != 100) {
        try {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.incrementProgressBy(2);
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(100);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        if (progressBar.getProgress() == 10) {
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Intent intent = new Intent("new_device");
                   intent.putExtra("device", model);
                   Context context = progressBar.getContext();
                   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
               }
           });
        }
     }
  }
}); 

thread.start();
```

Also make sure that `10` is ever reached (for example, the sequence could be `1-3-5-7-9-11` and you won’t get anything.

I also took context from the progress bar, you don’t need to fetch it first.

There are better solutions than this but I just kept your structure.

Comment: Thanks for the code! But this is also not working. BroadcastReceiver in other activity is not receiving anything. 
There are better solutions than this. Can you give me a an example or some hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: Also you have written thread.sleep(100); This should be Thread.sleep(100); right?

Comment: Yes. Progress bar editing is the only thing that comes to my mind. Are you getting any warning in your logcat?

Comment: Also, registering your receiver onCreate() is bad if your are unregistering onPause() or onStop().

Comment: No I am not getting any warning in my logcat. And I am unregistering it in onDestroy()